# Setting WMI permissions remotely on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, wmi

I am a programmer , I don know the server well.

I made a simple program checking the service on the remote server  is started or not.
by using this(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwd0y33x(v=VS.90).aspx)

but the permission should be set. and I can't find any document via the internet. except one document.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393266(VS.85).aspx

but the engineer say that 'tell me exactly what I do. there are many DCOM

are they any nice document to show him?

thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you if the programming is correct.  I can tell you that you should be able to check permissions by running a vbscript or powershell script using the same user as your application.  if you don't know vbscript you can use the [scriptomatic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd939957.aspx) to write one for you.  If you have powershell installed - that's easy

```
get-service -computer mytestcomputer
```

if either of those work I would look at your code

Comment: or if no powershell then



 wmic /node:servername process

Comment: The reason I went with powershell and didn't use WMIC is because powershell uses the exact same classes he's referencing.  WMIC is so "prepackaged", while I'm sure it could be used to diagnose a permissions problem, I'm afraid that it would autofix something like an impersonation problem.  The syntax to check a service is wmic /node:servername service